# preg_split спарсить аргументы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

помоги разобраться как сделать с помощью preg_split
`$message = 'test1 "test2 test2" test3';`
что бы было так:

```
$array[0] = test1
$array[1] = test2 test2
$array[3] = test3
```

делаю обработку команд

Comment: Как по мне, то тут лучше парсить таким образом: `str_getcsv($message, ' ');` [Пример в песочнице](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea15f49219f1bfd0078ce39c2dd85fab16bd7953)

Comment: спасибо большое!